# arbitrary branch showing via git log --decorate

Tags: git, branch

Below- after issuing a '`git log --oneline --decorate`', I see this single commit with (remote) dangling in the midst of the other commits.

```
7b942c2 (HEAD -> development, origin/development) Changed activity name from Keyguard to Snooze.
 [snip]
d27174e (remote) Added new icons, Added Billing SDK, started billing implementation and configured Main activity to be single instance.
[snip]
```

Questions:

1) Is 'remote' a default branch that comes with git? If not, I must have created it some time back then?

2) How did I manage to end up with a commit like this?

3) Is there a way I can fix this so that it does not show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is '`remote`' a default branch that comes with git?

No, it is not. You generally have `remotes/xxx/abranch` to list the remote tracking branches of your repo.

Try a `git branch -avv` to list all your branches, see if `git branch` alone list a local branch 'remote'.
If you see one, you can easily remove that pointer with `git branch -d remote`.
That won't affect the commit (which is accessible from other branches, so it will remain visible).

Comment: Thanks, yes it was listed as a branch via  'git branch'. I deleted it as you've instructed- commit is still there.